# implement reCAPTCHA in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I want to use reCAPTCHA v2 in my laravel project.

Currently, I had implemented successfully it in my login page with this tutorial: https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-google-recaptcha-integration

But when it comes to my register page, when the validation passed, the error message popped out like: `validation.captcha` , and I don't know why.

Can anyone tell what may the problem be? Or how cant I find the problem?

Here is my part of code:
Thank you so much!

Register.blade.php

```
  <div class="card-body">
  {{ html()->form('POST', route('frontend.auth.register.post'))->open() }}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ html()->label(__('validation.attributes.frontend.last_name'))->for('last_name') }}

        {{ html()->text('last_name')
                 ->class('form-control')
                 ->placeholder(__('validation.attributes.frontend.last_name'))
                 ->attribute('maxlength', 191)
                 ->required() }}
      </div>
    </div>
    @if(config('access.captcha.registration'))
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        @captcha
        {{ html()->hidden('captcha_status', 'true') }}
      </div>
      <!--col-->
    </div>
    <!--row-->
    @endif
    <!-- google reCAPTCHA -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" id="feedback-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY')}}"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group mb-0 clearfix">
          {{ form_submit(__('labels.frontend.auth.register_button')) }}
        </div>
        <!--form-group-->
      </div>
      <!--col-->
    </div>
    <!--row-->
    {{ html()->form()->close() }}
```

Rules\Recaptch.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Recaptcha implements Rule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $data = array(
            'secret'   => 'env('reCAPTCHA_SECRET')',
            'response' => $value
        );

        try {
            $verify = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($verify);
            return json_decode($response)->success;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function postLoginForm(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required', new Recaptcha()]
        ]);
    
        // Recaptcha passed, do what ever you need
        return route(home_route());
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'ReCaptcha verification failed.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720254/google-recaptcha-with-laravel

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I made a stupid mistake, seems that I had placed the codes below in the wrong files.

```
public function postLoginForm(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request, [
    'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required', new Recaptcha()]
  ]);
  // Recaptcha passed, do what ever you need
  return route(home_route());
}
```

The code above should be placed in controllers.